# How can I do web scraping through XPath from dynamic charts with multiple criteria options?

Tags: python, loops, xpath, request, screen-scraping

I am very new to scraping and programing in general.
That's why I am asking for help with the next issue.
There is a web site under the url.
I need to get data from dynamic charts.
The code has to be written with an option of looping through all the required days data represented for and an option of looping though all elements containing the data.

First issue is that I need somehow to get the data following the XPath.
And the second one is that I have to write the loop to get all
[the required inflammation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl3vW.png)

```
url = "https://www.oree.com.ua/index.php/control/results_mo/DAM"


from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time



browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)


elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/text()")
for element in elements:
    print(element)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Selenium is required here. You can get directly data from this mixed html/json object (change the date accordingly to your needs) :

```
https://www.oree.com.ua/index.php/PXS/get_pxs_hdata/04.04.2020/DAM/1
```

Then request with :

```
//tbody//tr/td[i]
```

Where i is the column of interest. Range of i is 3-7. Column 3 is "Sales volume, MW.h", 4 is "Purchase volume, MW.h", etc...

Output for sales volume (04/04/2020) :
[image: SlsVol]

Comment: Dear E.Wiest, it's greatly appreciated to get your advice. I did receive information for the current date using the code below. /// elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/*")
for element in elements:
        elements_1 = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        for element in elements_1:
            print(element.get_attribute("textContent"))
        if element == elements_1[-1]:
            break
        else:
            print("next") /// The big thing now is to go over the days I need data for. Could you have idea?

Comment: Increment the date (dd.mm.yyyy) contained in the url `https://www.oree.com.ua/index.php/PXS/get_pxs_hdata/dd.mm.yyyy/DAM/1` to scrape over multiple days and adapt your code accordingly. Between the 1st january 2020 and the 31th march we had 2184 values : https://framapic.org/WpmVEYepKnZM/F9HWH4tqHru2.PNG

Comment: Thank you sincerely for the advice. I have written code to get the data following the link you provided above. But iterating through days a bit complicated as for right now. Still have to figure out how to put the existing code into a loop through days.